# How can I use a provider in a custom widget to change the variables within a provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I tried to create a function to adjust the font size on the setting screen, so I made a provider.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CountPage extends ChangeNotifier{
  
  double _font = 40;
  double get font => _font;

  change_font_1()
  {
    _font = 30;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_font_2()
  {
    _font = 35;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_font_3()
  {
    _font = 40;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

And I created an option screen custom widget

Code related to font size:

```
class Option_page extends StatelessWidget {
  late CountPage _countPage;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[200],
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text("설정"),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: Column(children: [
          Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Row(children: [
                Container(child: Text('글자크기')),
                Container(
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _countPage.change_font_1();
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one_outlined)),
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _countPage.change_font_2();
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two_outlined)),
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _countPage.change_font_3();
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.looks_3_outlined)),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]))
        ]))));
  }
}
```

I connected with the main class:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      home:ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) =>  CountPage()
        ,child: Quote() ,)
      );
  }
}
```

Code related to font size in the main class:

```
class Quote extends StatelessWidget {
  Quote({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  late CountPage _countPage;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _countPage = Provider.of<CountPage>(context, listen: true);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Center(
                child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _countPage.page_down();
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left))),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      height: 400,
                      width: 350,
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        list[_countPage.page]["message"],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: _countPage.font,
                          fontFamily: 'snow',
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ))),
                ),
                Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      list[_countPage.page]["author"],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                    )))
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The font size does not change even if you run it on Chrome and press the font size change button. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I cant see `page_down`... method on your notifier class+ others data are missing, you can make the snippet minimal that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
I don't think it's polite to post all the codes, so I only posted the parts related to my question.

Comment: The part you said worked fine and didn't write the code.

Comment: try to make it minimal

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by minimal?

Comment: It's my first time programming, so the code is so dirty that I don't know how to show it.

Comment: I can test with `Option_page` on home, will it be ok

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't have the code to send you right now, but is there any way I can show you the whole code I wrote?
I'm afraid this is too much of a request for you.

Comment: ok push on git repo, also can you can tell the exact error message you are getting now. I think I've got one

Comment: Thank you very much for your hard work, but I don't know what git repo is.

Comment: I will quickly find out about git repo through Google and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the MaterialApp to access provider on all route

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => CountPage(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        home: Quote(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From current snippet, you didnt assign the `CountPage` on `Option_page`.

```dart
class Option_page extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CountPage _countPage = Provider.of<CountPage>(context, listen: true); //this ibe 
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
```

Comment: I tried that method, but then an error message occurred.

Comment: I just uploaded my project folder on GitHub, do you want to come see it?

Comment: I can invite you.

Comment: ok, share the link or you can find by `yeasin50`

Comment: I sent an invitation.

Comment: Thank you so much for accepting the invitation. Is there any way I can send you a personal message?

Comment: The main issue you are talking about occurs when you use drawer item to navigate new page ?

Comment: That's right. If you click the drawer item, an error occurs.

Comment: If I erase the code you told me, 
The page does open, but pressing the button on the new page does not change the font size.

Comment: Got it, there are two ways I know to overcome this, you can wrap the materialApp with Provider or pass provider value while navigating

Comment: I just saw the code you posted. 
I was surprised to see your code. 
I'm truly grateful to you.

Comment: Glad to help. Make all changes that i think was needed, also you can rearrange a little bit to make it cleaner. you can merge it it now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
Thanks to you, I got the courage to solve the project until the end.